# Solving Degree 2 Partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Please, can anyone help me solving this problem?

$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}−(\frac{\partial U}{\partial x})^2=0$$

where $U=U(x,t)$

with side condition as $U(x,0)=\cos x$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. What have you tried?

Comment: I have no idea about how to proceed, probably I am thinking of taking differential with respect to x so that the resulting equation would be second order non linear PDE

Answer (score 0):

$$U_t-(U_x)^2=0$$
HINT :
$$U_{xt}-2U_{xx}U_x=0$$
Let $\quad V(x,t)=U_x(x,t)$

$V_x=U_{xx}$ and $V_t=U_{xt}$
$$V_t-2V_xV=0$$
This is a Burger's equation which is well documented in the literature.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation